# SwiftUI with ObservableObject - List having NavigationLink to details downloading it on scroll NOT on appear

Tags: api, download, swiftui, ios13, combine

I have list of cities

```
struct CityListView: View {

    @ObservedObject private(set) var citiesViewModel: CitiesViewModel

    var body: some View {
        LoadingView(isShowing: .constant(citiesViewModel.cities?.isEmpty ?? false)) {
            NavigationView {
                List(self.citiesViewModel.cities ?? []) { city in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(cityName: city.name,
                                                                    detailCityModel: DetailCityModel(cityId: city.id))) {
                                                                        Text(city.name)
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Cities"), displayMode: .large)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and when I'm scrolling the list, the DetailCityModel inits and download data from API. How to  downloading (or init DetailCityModel) on DetailView's appearance, not for showing item with NAvigationLink to DetailView?

Answer (score 1):

You have to kick off the API call in onAppear() not in the initialiser of DetailView.